# Can low brigtness extend life of CCFL lamp in laptop LCD backlight?

Tags: ccfl

I have really good and old laptop (IBM t60p with t61p board). I just replaced whole screen because CCFL lamp died after many years.

Can I extend life of CCFL by using laptop with reduced brightness when I don't need 100%?

It is hard to find new LCD or CCFL for this model, I want it to last another few years.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Actually, to my knowledge, cold cathode lighting sources can have their life shortened by a lower brightness. It uses thermionic emission, and thus heat assists it's operation. Likewise, the gas inside the tube is turned into a plasma, allowing easier current flow. When you lower the brightness you also lower the current flow, which further causes issues.

Comment: And this is what I was worried about.